# Gigabyte GC-WB867d-i not working under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless

Yesterday I bought a WiFi card for my PC because I wanted to remove my old one, which only have 2.4GHz.

But now if I start my PC with the new gigabyte card, no WiFi appears. Also with `ifconfig` I cannot find the WiFi card. So I think I need an additional driver, maybe?

Do you have any idea how the WiFi card can work under my system?

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
```

`uname -r  -> 3.19.0-65-generic`

If I type `dmesg | grep iwl` I don't get an output

Comment: According to online sources it has several different revisions with Intel chipsets. Please edit and add the information regarding yours, revision number and/or the result of *lspci*.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details about the card. From the terminal: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Hey @chili555: 

Sorry for my late answer. 
Output:

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)

Comment: Hey @CelticWarrior 

M.2/rev4.2

Comment: Please add: `uname -r` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @Bernhard I already edited your question and added the info regarding the hardware so it won't be lost in comments. Please edit yourself the next time and include the requested outputs above.

Comment: @chili555 `uname -r  -> 3.19.0-65-generic`

If I type `dmesg | grep iwl` I don't get an output

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 24F3`